# How to use the lookup plugin to get the directory path and file in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a two playbooks where one creates SSH Keys and the other one creates a new user and deploys the public ssh key for the new user created.

My issue is I created a task that create a new directory with a timestamp to store the relevant data, I was able to get the path to a variable where I added it as a dummy host so that I can be able to call that path with all my plays but it seems like I am unable to use the same variable in lookup so that I can be able to deploy the ssh key. Kindly assist, below are the relevant tasks.

```yaml
# Create the directory with timestamp
- name: Create Directory with timestamp to store data that was run multiple times that day
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['local']
  file:
    path: "{{store_files_path}}/{{ansible_date_time.date}}/{{ansible_date_time.time}}"
    state: directory
    mode: "0755"
  register: dir_path
```

```yaml
# Add the directory path to dummy host called save so that I can call it from other plays
- name: Add dir path:"{{dir_path.path}}" as a 'save' host
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['local']
  add_host:
    name: "save"
    dir: "{{dir_path.path}}"
```

```yaml
# Deploying SSH Key I tried this -->
- name: Deploy Public Key to the server
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['Servers']
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{hostvars['new-user']['user']}}"
    state: present
    key: "{{dir_path.path}}/SSH-Key.pub"
```

```yaml
# ...this -->
- name: Deploy Public Key to the server
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['Servers']
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{hostvars['new-user']['user']}}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file','{{dir_path.path}}/SSH-Key.pub') }}"
```

```yaml
# .... and this -->
- name: Deploy Public Key to the server
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['Servers']
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{hostvars['new-user']['user']}}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file','{{hostvars['save']['dir']}}/SSH-Key.pub') }}"
```

None of them worked, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a Jinja expression into a string in a Jinja expression, then you indeed end up with a your variable not being interpreted.

A basic example of this is:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ '{{ foo }}' }}"
      vars:
        foo: bar
```

Which gives:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "{{ foo }}"
}
```

When

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ foo }}"
      vars:
        foo: bar
```

Gives thes expected:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "bar"
}
```

---

So in order to achieve what you want here, you should use the concatenation operator of Jinja: [`~`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators), in order to let Jinja interpret your variable and concatenate it with the rest of your "hardcoded" string.

Effectively ending with the instruction:

```yaml
key: "{{ lookup('file', hostvars['save']['dir'] ~ '/SSH-Key.pub') }}"
```

Comment: Hey this seems not to work because this variable has been created in a different play... how can I overcome that??

Comment: this variable: `dir_path.path`

Comment: Mhm... then do it a single playbook, what's the point to do it in two separate playbooks?

Comment: Because that's a task that was created in the first playbook. There is no way of doing that by using this ... `key: "{{ lookup('file','{{hostvars['save']['dir']}}/SSH-Key.pub') }}"`

Comment: There is, apply the same explanation as above: don't put a Jinja expression in a string or it will evaluate as a simple string. Rather concatenate your variable with the "hardcoded" string.